# How to insert data if not exist else update it?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, xampp

I want to update row if exists in table `bag` else insert new row

these types of columns that I used it in table bag

```
car_name : varchar
p_id : int
quantity : int
price_one_piece : int
```

I make `car_name`  and `p_id`  as primary (composite key)

I write this code in MySQL routine in xampp  and it saves in xampp without errors  but when I tries to execute it in xampp it makes error that says

> The following query has failed: "SET @p0='mohamed'; SET @p1='1'; SET @p2='1'; SET @p3='1'; CALL `bag_insert`(@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3); "
>   MySQL said:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry 'car_name-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Code:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM bag WHERE p_id = p_id and `car_name`= car_name)THEN 
UPDATE bag set`car_name`='car_name',`p_id`=p_id,`quantity`=quantity,`price_one_piece`=price_one_piece WHERE `p_id`=p_id;

ELSE 
INSERT INTO bag (car_name,p_id,quantity,price_one_piece) VALUES (car_name,p_id,quantity,price_one_piece); 
END IF
```

Comment: Why not use `ON DUPLICATE KEY`?

Comment: how to use it when I make composite key as primary

Comment: It is usually not a good idea to have stored procedures' parameter names be ambiguous/identical to the field names in the tables the procedure will be accessing. It makes it harder to read, and often MySQL will use the one you do not expect. I would not be surprised if the error is coming from the UPDATE affecting multiple rows.

Comment: Any key collision will trigger it. You can define whatever behaviour you want at that point.

Comment: I make car_name and p_id as primary (composite key)

Comment: how to use ON DUPLICATE KEY?

Comment: but when use i use INSERT INTO bag VALUES (:car_name, :p_id, :quantity, :price_one_piece) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = :quantity, price_one_piece = :price_one_piece ; it   makes error    MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':car_name,:p_id,:quantity,:price_one_piece) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = :' at line 1

Comment: Lose the colons (:)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem using

```
> replace INSERT INTO bag (car_name,p_id,quantity,price_one_piece)
> VALUES (car_name,p_id,quantity,price_one_piece);
```

I found solution in https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/